# How do I view the OS installation date on Solaris 10?

Tags: operating-systems, shell-script, solaris

How can I find out the system installation date on Solaris?

Objective is to verify the date and time that the OS was created (OS creation timestamp).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ls -lrt /var/sadm/system/logs` 
look for `begin.log_xxxxxx` or `finish.log_xxxxxxx`

Example:

## ls -lrt

total 799

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Nov 15 2006 begin.log -> begin.log_2006_11_15
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 90 Nov 15 2006 begin.log_2006_11_15
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21 Nov 15 2006 finish.log -> finish.log_2006_11_15
```

The symfile name and the timestamp both match the date installed.